# Storing Data for Google Data Studio

Tags: sql, database, looker-studio

I have an application that makes reports available by http in either CSV or JSON format. I want this data to be accessible to Google Data Studio. I was considering building a connector to access the data, but the number of rows that can be accessed at any given time is quite small and there is a daily data limit. So I want to build a system to download the reports daily and store them to be accessed by Data Studio. I created a script to load the reports into a Google Cloud SQL but this is quite expensive because of the base cost of running a Google Cloud SQL machine. Any ideas how else to deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firebase Realtime Database.
I used it before for storing 1G Data and 20k rows.
I have code samples for that.

Comment: Thanks, yes this could work. I don't have any experience with NoSQL (and very little with SQL), is there any disadvantage to having all the data in JSON format? I guess Data Studio will specify all the data types so a SQL database isn't really necessary, is that the thinking?

Comment: no worry about that. Firebase Realtime db is just a Json tree. In a nutshell. It contains a big json object instead records. so You can easily import it to data studio.

Comment: Are you running through Big Query or direct into Data Studio?

Comment: If you give me the project, I will do it at low cost.